# array index out of bounds exception: 12

Tags: java

This code is really simple, but I just can't get it to work. It keeps saying the array goes out of bounds at line 8 (the while loop) and I have no idea why, cause `u` gets reset every time. Any ideas? It's probably a simple solution but thanks for the help.

```
public class potato {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year;
        int day = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis() + java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()) / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0 / 24.0);
        int[] months = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        int u;
        for (year = 1970; year < 2018; year++) {
            u = 0;
            while (day > months[u] && u < 12) {
                day -= months[u];
                u++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of the variable u before checking the days. Change while loop condition to

```
 while ( u < 12 && day > months[u] )
```

Comment: oh it worked! thanks a bunch. why is that different though? i dont understand.

Comment: You are welcome. I edited the answer to include why it happened :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely here

```
 u = 0;
 while (day > months[u] && u < 12) {
                    day -= months[u];
                    u++;
                }
```

you are actually accessing the array in the while loop header when you incremented it. It test the array again which cause `months[12]` which is out of bound.

Similar to the previous answer when you say `while(u<12&&day>months[u])` it uses the short circuit methods of testing. So when `u==12` it immediately cancel entering the loop and also cancel testing the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your while condition.

```
int monthsLength = months.length()-1;
// So it contains 0-11 index values
```

// But in your condition it checks 12 index
in months[u]. This throws index out of bounds exception.
  Please modify your while condition to :
    while (day > months[u] && u < monthsLength)
I hope this will work!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not an answer for the queston, but. I have looked at this code example and I have some notes.

1. It is not clear what this code does.
2. When you work with `date` it is strongly recommend to use special classes: `Calendar` or `YodaTime`.
3. I don't know why, but you do not worry about different days in `Febriary` in leap year.
4. `System.currentTimeMillis()` retruns milliseconds between the current time and midnight, `January 1, 1970 UTC`: so it is not clear why you use `1970` in code.

As code example, look at this one. Maybee it could help you.

```
public static int getDays(int yearFrom, int yearTo) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int days = getTotalDays(yearFrom, yearTo, calendar);

    for (int year = yearFrom; year < yearTo; year++) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        for (int month = Calendar.JANUARY; month <= Calendar.DECEMBER; month++) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            int maxDayOfMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            if (days <= maxDayOfMonth)
                break;

            days -= maxDayOfMonth;
        }
    }

    return days;
}

private static int getTotalDays(int yearFrom, int yearTo, Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    int days = 0;

    for (int year = yearFrom; year < yearTo; year++) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        days += calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    }

    return days;
}
```

***P.S.*** I don't know context of this task, but according to the code, you could avoid all loops between 1970 and 1917 years and work only with current year.